# Are there any downsides to buying a third party extension tubes for Canon?

Tags: lens, canon, macro, extension-tubes

I would like to get a little higher magnification out of my Canon 100mm Macro, so I am looking at extension tubes.

I know Canon makes the EF25, but it seems pretty expensive considering there isn't even glass involved. I saw a "Kenko" extension tube set that is only a little more expensive for a 12, 20, and 36mm.  Are there any downsides to buying a third party extension tube?

Comment: I have the Kenko tubes, and they work fine. (Note that I don't have any EF-S lenses, though.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know there should be no real difference. The extension tube have no lens elements but is merely (as the name suggests) a tube. The Kenko extension tubes feature the same electrical connections as the Canon one (judging from reviews and images on the net). [According to this review](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Kenko-Extension-Tube-Set-Review.aspx), there are two versions of the Kenko tubes; an older one that is not compatible with EF-S lenses, and a newer one that is. Worth keeping in mind if you have such lenses.

Comment: Good to know that there are 2 version, I'd certainly want the one supporting EF-S.

Comment: I got the Kenko tubes from Amazon.  I emailed the various resellers -- I think these days you are unlikely to see the older version.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any downside, it may be in utilizing different materials for the tubes. I don't know if it actually so - and I won't be surprised if it is - but it is possible that 3rd party tubes are made of a more elastic metal or thinner walls (the cheaper you go , the more likely it is). It means that once supporting the weight of the lens, the tube will bend a little, creating some degree of axis offset and asymmetry. The effect should be the same as a tilt-lens at very small tilts.

That said, I did not hear some specifically bad things on the Kenkos, and as an *electrical* tubes they are considered a good alternative to the Canons.